# Generate pages based on url using Javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

At the moment I can generate pages by drawing the content with javascript based on ajax requests for JSON files which describe what is to be drawn.

The result is good, but I want users to be able to access a page such as www.example.com/SomePage where I use SomePage in javascript to display the content based on it.

Since SomePage isn't an actual existing .aspx page I get 404 error from the server. Could I capture the url path and hand it somehow to the javascript to generate the page dynamically? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if there's isn't a page to serve...then there won't be any javascript (because javascript lives in, or is referenced from, a page). You'd need some sort of URL rewriting on the server-side which would cause a redirect to your real page, perhaps containing query string parameters that indicate what the content should be. IIS has a rewriting module to do this, or if you're using MVC you might be able to create some routing rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look for the [HttpContext.RewritePath Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wkk6d(v=vs.110).aspx).

In a short, you read your path eg: **www.example.com/SomePage**

and using the `HttpContext.RewritePath` you translated it to

```
www.example.com/editor.aspx?id=SomePage
```

and there you have your `SomePage` value to use
on your `javascript` code
and still the url show `www.example.com/SomePage`